# @PathParam to Object in Resteasy inside EJB

Tags: resteasy, ejb-3.1

Good morning guys,

I have a problem to implement a @ PathParam referencing a EntityBean within an EJB 
I did a test with a class without annotations of EJB and it worked, but when I put this method inside an EJB the error. 
He is lost when executing the method [method.invoke (locator, args)] in ResourceLocator class that is the core RESTEasy. 
Following test data and errors.
Thanks for any help.

**Work!**

```
@Path("/continent")
public class ContinentWSTest {

    @Override
    public Response listContinent(@PathParam("continentPK") ContinentPK continentPK) {
        System.out.println("Ok!");
        return Response.ok(continentBean).build();
    }

}
```

**Dont't work!**

```
public interface ContinentWS {

    @GET
    @Path("/{continentPK}")
    Response listContinent(@PathParam("continentPK") ContinentPK continentPK);

}

@Stateless
@Path("/continent")
public class ContinentWSImpl implements ContinentWS {

    @Override
    public Response listContinent(@PathParam("continentPK") ContinentPK continentPK) {
        ContinentBean continentBean = continentServiceLocal.findByPK(continentPK);
        return Response.ok(continentBean).build();
    }

}
```

**Log's**

07:42:13,287 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Unknown exception while executing GET /continent/1: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocator.createResource(ResourceLocator.java:64) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocator.createResource(ResourceLocator.java:53) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocator.invoke(ResourceLocator.java:90) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem. 
This error was happening because the @ Path needs to stay in the EJB interface and the interface needs to be defined as @ Local or @ Remote